# Why is innodb engine disabled by default in ubuntu 13.10 mysql server?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, innodb

We all know that InnoDB is the default engine as of MySQL 5.5 but ... 
for some reason an extra configuration file zentyal.cnf is included in MySQL's `conf.d` directory when installing mysql server package in Ubuntu 13.10.

This can really throw you as your choice of engine in your `create table ... engine=innodb;` statements are completely ignored.

Was there a good reason for adding zentyal.cnf? I will report this as a bug on Ubuntu's Launchpad.

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't come with zentyal.cnf unless you install Zentyal (http://www.zentyal.org/). It's definitely not built into Ubuntu's MySQL packages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update:

**Answer:** It is *not* installed by default.

(Note to self: Now eat Humble Pie.)
I am pretty sure now that Zentyal *was* installed explicitly by us - despite what I'd previously supposed - and that this was the cause of the problem (even though we also presumably uninstalled Zentyal with `apt-get`).

The remedy is ... still ...

1. Remove `zentyal.cnf` from `/etc/mysql/conf.d` and
2. then  `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question... which is weird because you asked the question.

Comment: Answer is now complete even though I do not like the question which I would delete  but ... maybe someone else would benefit from knowing that `zentyal.cnf` may be lurking there undeleted after attempted Zentyal uninstall.